# Calculate normalized score between two numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, dataset

I trying to score how one number is similar to another number in one set and then create final score between normalized scores from all sets to get average score
100% similarity should occur when two numbers are same

e.g.
first set
reference number: 0
numbers that I want rate based on reference number: 1, -1, 2, -2

second set
reference number: 600
numbers that I want rate based on reference number: 700, -700, 800, -800

Does anyone know how this type of problem should be approached?

I'm trying to get score between two numbers using theirs difference, but I don't know how to normalized this difference into some closed rage which can be used between other sets like [0;100], [0;1]

first set

```
|0 - 1| = 1
|0 - (-1)| = 1
|0 - 2| = 2
|0 - (-2)| = 2
```

second set

```
|600 - 700| = 100
|600 - (-700)| = 1300
|600 - 800| = 200
|600 - (-800)| = 1400
```

Comment: A simple possibility is to normalise by the span of the set : `s = vmax - vmin`. Then `f(a,b) = 100 * (1 - abs(a-b) / s)`.

Comment: Thanks! it seems to be working, does this formula have name? I try it on first set and to get score 0 I must pass to the function b parameter equal to 4 or -4, why is that? I supposed b should be 2 or -2 to get score equal 0

Comment: `s` is equal to 4 for the first step so it should work for 2 and -2. I don´t know the name. More sophisticated formulas exist.

Comment: for 2 and -2 I'm getting score equal to 50, score shouldn't be 0 while this numbers are extremes of compartment? "More sophisticated formulas exist." under what names should I look for?

Comment: I don´t understand.  `1 - (2 + 2)/4 = 0`.

Comment: I thought that parameter a is the reference number(our best number to which we score other numbers) and parameter b is the number for what we want to get the score, how should I think about a, b? e.g. `100* (1 - (0 + 2)/4) = 50`

Comment: If a = 0 is the reference number, ,  then take s=2

Comment: how it's refer to `s = vmax - vmin`, which numbers did you substituted for vmax, vmin? does vmax isn't max value from set and vmin min value from set, in first set case vmax=2 and vmin=-2

Comment: You can take s=max(max-ref, ref-min). Anyway, the difference for which similarity is equal to 0 is rather arbitrary. It depends on the exact use case.